# How to return number of array item? Why Unfortunately Stopped?

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I'm trying to return numer of array elements in TextView. When I run it, application stopped unfortunately in android. Coding bad or need to add some codes? I just add the code below only. I don't edit or programm others. Just like this New Project>Android Appliac..Pro..> Next >next... then I edited only onCreate function only below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    String[] btn = { "Google", "Yahoo", "Twitter" };
    TextView txt=new TextView(this);
    txt.setText(btn.length);
    layout.addView(txt);
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: You need to _at least_ show us a stack trace.

Comment: "Coding bad". :) Also, worry not @MattBall, I got it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
 txt.setText(btn.length)
```

`btn.length` returns an integer. This is attempting to set the text value to a string resource you veeery probably don't have. Try:

```
 txt.setText("" + btn.length)
```